# Where does the extra candy come from when I evolve a pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

Every time that I evloved a pokemon, regardless of the price of evolution in candies, after the evolution has happened I've got 1 extra candy left. For example evolving a Voltorb into an Electrode with 67 candies, would leave me with 18 candies and not 17 as expected (The evolution costs 50 candies). But, if I'm lacking only one candy for the required amount (49 in the case of Voltorb), I'm unable to evolve.

Where does that extra candy come from?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have one extra candy because you get one candy for evolving pokemon. You still need 50 candies to evolve a Voltorb, but you get one candy back for evolving him.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you lose a Pokemon, you get a candy.  The traditional way to do this is to trade it in.

But evolving consists of losing the lower tier one and getting a new upper tier one with similar state.

You can then trade in the new upper tier Pokemon, making the total candy required to evolve K Pokemon with an apparent cost of N is: K(N-2)+2.

Comment: Maybe it's because it's monday morning but I don't see how that formula relates to your explanation. Also, if I evolve 1 pokemon (K=1)  with cost 50 (N=50), your formula says the net cost (after trading in the evolved pokemon) is 50-2+2 = 50 ?

Comment: -@hertitu suppose you have 202 pidgie candy.  How many pidgie can you evolve?  202/12 is wrong, the answer is (202-2)/(12-2)=20 after you account for the candy you can get back from evolution and from the evolved pokemon.  Or, cost 12, 20 pokemon, candy required is 2+20*(12-2)=202.  In short, it takss 2 less candy per pokemon after returned candy, but it also takes 2 to prime the pump.

Comment: Ok thanks, I see now that I had misinterpreted the "total candy required" as net cost, where you meant it as the starting requirement. In other words: if you evolve 5 pidgies then your candy level will drop from e.g. 52 to 2 so the net cost is K(N-2)=50, whereas your formula (correctly) says how many candy you need (52) before you can evolve 5 pidgies.